# Odoo12 Domain condition with OR and AND logic

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I can't understand the logic to create a condition with multiple and/or clause, the domain i want to reproduce is :

`(Field1=A or Field2=B) AND Field3=C and Field4!=D`

On my search view, on the field domain i tried:

```
domain="[(('&amp;',('field4','!=',False),('Field3','=',False)),('|',('Field1','ilike','X'),('Field2','ilike','Y')))]"

domain="[(''&amp;'',('&amp;',('field4','!=',False),('Field3','=',False)),('|',('Field1','ilike','X'),('Field2','ilike','Y')))]"
```

when i try the filter I've this error:

```
 in distribute_not
    elif token in DOMAIN_OPERATORS_NEGATION:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Someone could explain me the correct logic to build a multiple condition with different operators in domain?

Answer (score 1):

Following this links i've understood how it works :

[Understanding OpenERP Domain Filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998921/understanding-openerp-domain-filter)

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715062/odoo-domain-filter-isnt-working)

[enter link description here](https://www.odoo.com/it_IT/forum/help-1/question/understanding-openerp-domain-filter-58405)

In my case the right domain is :

```
domain="['&amp;',('Field4','!=',False),('Field3','=',False),'|',('Field1','ilike','X'),('Field2','ilike','Y')]"
```

Answer (score 1):

ODOO domain follows the prefix expressions. You can generate your own domain condition understanding it or

> from odoo.osv import expression

and use `expression.AND(list_of_conditions)` and `expression.OR(list_of_conditions)` to generate your domain.

here in your case (Field1=A or Field2=B) AND Field3=C and Field4!=D, this can be termed as (conditionA OR conditionB) AND conditionC AND conditionD. So the expression will be

> expression.AND([expression.OR([conditionA, conditionB]), conditionC,
> conditionD])

Comment: Thank you OmaL I didn't know this second option.